# Transformation that keeps Poisson process invariant in Lie groups

Tags: stochastic-processes, lie-groups, stochastic-analysis, poisson-process, levy-processes

As we know that the Brownian motion is invariant under orthogonal transformation ,

*see article of Bernt Oksendal for more details : **https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01045159**.*page 215 corollary 1.

My question is : what is the transformation that keeps Poisson process invariant ?

Means that,do we have a theorem or article that answer this like for the case of the Brownian Motion?

Thanks :)

Comment: I guess if $\mu$ is the intensity measure of your Poisson process and $T$ is the transformation, you'd need $\mu\circ T^{-1}=\mu$ for the Poisson process to be invariant under $T$.

Comment: @SmallDeviation   yes i guess so !